# Xquery 1.0 - query to get the average of some elements, and put that average back in the same place

Tags: xpath, xquery

So I have an XML file like this:

```
<data>
    <person name="john" lastname="doe" >
        <grades>
            <math>90</math>
            <biology>23</biology>
        </grades>
    </person>
    .
    .
```

I know how to query this to get the average of all the grades, but I want to take that average and put it in the exact same place that grades are in for the original xml file, replacing grades. So I would have something like:

```
<data>
    <person name="john" lastname="doe" >
        <average>56.5</average> 
    </person>
    .
    .
```

edit: I actually figured out a way to get the needed results internally, thanks for the suggestion to this problem though, it may help me in the future.

Comment: Im using xquery 1.0. I'm trying to find if there's a way to do this with xquery. . even if it means something a bit messy

Comment: Considering your question history, you seem to be passing your homework to Stack Overflow without even trying. People here don't like that _at all_ (and your professor might not like it, either). Expect helpful answers if you show what you tried, otherwise you're risking a heavy number of downvotes.

Comment: This isn't homework, it's a set of interview related questions.

I've actually been trying this one quite a bit, but I'm new to Xquery.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, XQuery can't literally returns modified XML. You will have to recreate the XML, and this get overly complicated given a complex XML document to start.

For this fairly simple XML structure though, you can use the following XQuery to return the expected XML :

```
<data>
{
    for $p in /data/person
    let $g := $p/grades/*
    return 
        <person>
        {
            $p/@*,
            <average>{sum($g) div count($g)}</average>
        }
        </person>
}
</data>
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/87e8c2d5e347aed02edfc4d6d515d117)</kbd>**